# How to truncate text in a table column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, ellipsis

I am trying to create a table where each column fits the width of the content (just like a normal table), but when the content would push the table beyond 100% of the container width, certain long columns would be truncated with an ellipsis.

```
+-------------+------------+------+
|some content | short text | more |
+-------------+------------+------+

+-------------+------------------------------------------------+------+
|some content | much longer text that forces the table wide... | more |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------+------+
```

It appears that any use of text-overflow: ellipsis requires a fixed-width table, and perhaps fixed-width columns. This is unfortunate because columns will no longer adjust their widths to fit content automatically.

I'm not tied to using a `<table>`. I've also attempted to do it using Bootstrap's `col-auto`. col-auto adjusts the width of the column to the content, but like `<table>` it refuses to truncate text when the table gets too wide.

Is this even possible?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nsf04tce/2/

Comment: Just guessing here, but what if you set a `max-width` on table or column? Presumably then you'd still get some responsiveness at narrower widths?

Comment: max-width does work on the td, but not on the table. I've added a fiddle above. @Marc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this without setting the `width` of the 'long' table cell.

Here are the ingredients:

Add `border-collapse: collapse` and `table-layout: fixed` to the `table` class and give a `width` instead of a `max-width`.

- The `border-collapse: collapse` will give all cells one shared border.
- The `table-layout: fixed` sets a fixed width.
- Use `width` to set a fixed width instead of a `max-width` (can grow to...).

Next to this, add `overflow: hidden` to the long table cell (next to the initial additions you made), so it knows what to do if the content overflows.

In CSS:

```css
.mytable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.long-td {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Demo:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.mytable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 400px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.long-td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
max-width on the table is ignored when nowrap and text-overflow is present:
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>short</td>
    <td class="long-td">long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long </td>
    <td>short</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***EDIT***

If you are not bound to use of a `table`, you could use a `div` with `span` elements inside. The `.mytable` div gets `display: flex` and `flex-flow: row nowrap` to make sure it stretches out.

CSS:

```css
.mytable {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.mytable {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.long-td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
max-width on the table is ignored when nowrap and text-overflow is present:
<div class="mytable">
  <span>short</span>
  <span class="long-td">long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long </span>
  <span>short</span>
</div>
```

***EDIT 2***

If you could use `display: grid`, you could specify a grid where the middle column is `auto` or a multiplier of a (fr)agment, like `4fr`. You could set the first and last column to a specified width. There are a lot of options for `grid-template-columns`, [see the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).

```css
.mytable {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}
```

```css
div > div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.mytable {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.long-td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
max-width on the table is ignored when nowrap and text-overflow is present:
<div class="mytable">
  <div>short</div>
  <div class="long-td">long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</div>
  <div>shorter story</div>
    <div>short</div>
  <div class="long-td">Suspendisse cursus ornare rutrum. Pellentesque sollicitudin bibendum odio, vitae euismod ligula.</div>
  <div>shorter story</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The difficulty here is that the table isn't sizing the columns to fit the content (see the width of the "short" columns), and the hard-coded table width forces a narrow table wider than I want. See the two sample tables at the top of my question.

Comment: @ccleve Ah yes, I see now. Does it need to be tables? I added another example when using `display: flex`.

Comment: Just deleted my earlier comment. This display:flex approach doesn't work because the columns aren't lined up. You can't have more than one row. Although I suppose it could work if you put more than one row in a column, though.

Comment: @ccleve I added another option, this time with `display: grid`.

Comment: Almost there. Possibly make it so the table isn't width: 100%? Just wide enough to hold content?

Comment: @ccleve That's possible with `grid-template-colums` as I explained.